# Local WordPress installation doesn't crop images

Tags: images, admin, cropping

When I try to crop an image in the WordPress backend area of my custom theme, I get the message "There has been an error cropping your image". I have it set up on a local machine using XAMPP. When I set up the exact same theme on a server, it works perfectly fine.

I checked quite some questions that seemed to be similar to my problem, but nothing worked so far.

I disabled all plugins. I checked the php.ini for `extension=php_gd2.dll`, which is not uncommented. I don't know what else could be the problem.

Interestingly when I change the theme to "Twenty Eleven" cropping images works.

Comment: Your theme might be forcing WordPress to use a specific image library to crop the images which is not supported, you might want to look that one up.

Comment: In addition to the Jack Johansson comment, possible your theme tries to write to not writable folder. And on the server this folder is writable for some reason

Answer (score 3):

For the record since I ended up here when experiencing the same issue on my localhost:

1. In php.ini, Uncomment the line with: extension=php_gd2.dll
2. Restart apache / all services

This sorted it out for me (I may have switched a few other services on while I was there, but I believe this is what fixed it!)